# What is the difference of internalWebPropertyId, defaultProfileId and profileId in a Google Analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am playing with Google Analytics API and found that it's really complicated.

A GA user can have more than one accounts.

Each accounts can have more than one Web Properties

Each Property can have "internalWebPropertyId", "defaultProfileId" and ordinary profile id.

I might have already made some mistakes by listing them out.

Is there any tutorial/manual that I can read to understand the whole structure better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A user can have access to more then one Google Analytics accounts -> Each account can have one or more Web Propertys -> each Web property can have one or more Views (profiles)

Don't rely to much on `DefaultProfileid` its not set for every `webProperty` and I haven't been able to find any documentation as to how that's set.

You can read a little about it here:  [Accounts and Views (Profiles)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsAccounts) as well as [What Is The Management API - Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/)

I just found this in answer:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/~all/webproperties/~all/profiles?oauth_token={Token}
```

There should be away of working that to make one request for accounts, one to get all the Web Properties , then one to get all the Profiles.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I love `DefaultProfileId` is just because I can get all the profile id by one query from `handleWebproperties` of `gapi.client.analytics.management.webproperties.list`. Otherwise I have to use the `accountId` and `webpropertyId` pair to retrieve the expected profile id for every profile. I have 100+ profiles and that is a lot.